# Why is the trivial topology on $X$ simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Why is the trivial topology on $X$ simply connected?
Given a topology consisting of $X$ and $\emptyset$, why is $X$ simply connected?

I'm pretty sure that the trivial topology implies that every path (continuous function) can only have 2 values. I'm not sure how to continue from here. Any help would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's the other way around: If $X$ has trivial topology and $Y$ is any topological space, all maps $f: Y \to X$ are continuous. In particular, fix $p\in X$, for any $f: \mathbb S^1 \to X$, the map

$$F(x, t) = \begin{cases} f(x) & t=0\\ 
\text{anything} & \text{if }0<t<1\\
p & \text{if }t=1
\end{cases}$$

give a continuous homotopy between $f$ and the constant map.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Generally, why do we look at functions from $S^1 \rightarrow X$ and not from $[0,1] \rightarrow X$ ?

Comment: A space $X$ is simply connected if all continuous map $f: \mathbb S^1 \to X$ are homotopic to a constant map. So that's why I use $\mathbb S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be sure. Every path is continuous. Every application $Y\rightarrow X$ is continuous. (It is evident because the preimages of the two only open sets are open in $Y$).

So if you take one path $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=x_0$ in $(X,x_0)$, you take $\gamma_s(t)=\gamma(t)$ if $s<1$ and $\gamma_s(t)=x_0$ is $s=1$. It is continuous (cf. supra), so it is an homotopy of $\gamma$ to the trivial path.